# DistributedTransactions on Linux

Tags: linux, distributed-transactions, transactionmanager, distributed-database

I am new to Distributed databases and the initial roadblock am facing is to have a distributed transaction across heterogeneous databases where the control goes to Transaction Manager which is mostly the OS implementation (MSDTC in Windows).
How are generally Distributed Transactions implemented on Linux?
And if they are implemented which major databases have support for it? (MSSQL, MYSQL, POSTGRES, ORACLE, SYBASE)

Comment: This is going to be a critical issue, like yesterday.  ACID is back, and there's a lot of catching up to do. Microsoft better get MSDTC working on Linux ASAP or .NET Core's portability is useless, because all these systems break without reliable distributed transactions that are easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any service like MSDTC in Linux. I expect you will need to use some `3rd party` transaction manager. Or maybe you could try to port MSDTC to Linux on Mono (no idea how hard it is or if possible).

*I'm not much familiar with transaction managers other than for Java.*

Comment: Wow. So that kills .NET Core's portability.